# configuring AlloOverride got Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to configure my apache because my .htaccess is not working, I tried to set `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in my

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

but I got an Internal Server Error.

this is my configuration now...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone has an idea about my case?

this is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

in the error logs, I got this:

```
[Wed Mar 05 10:30:43 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 05 10:32:21 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Mar 05 10:32:22 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: check the log and send whats in there and show your htaccess

Comment: You don't need `All` in `<Directory />`

Comment: I changed back the `<Directory />` to `None` but I got the same error...

Comment: Can you check Apache's error.log